# ERROR: Could not contact the SSO server

Tags: biztalk, single-sign-on, biztalk-deployment

I'm getting the following error on my dev machine when attempting to manage SSO settings:

```
ERROR: 0xC0002A0F : Could not contact the SSO server 'SSODB'. Check that SSO is
configured and that the SSO service is running on that server.
```

The Enterprise Single Sign-On Service, RPC service, and COM+ System Application service were all started when I checked, but I gave them a restart anyway and it didn't fix the problem.  I can access the SSODB through SSMS.

I unconfigured SSO through BizTalk and reconfigured it (successfully).  Alas, this also did not help.

SSO was previously working fine.  I did notice this morning upon reboot that my browser home page was reset back to our corporate site (meaning something may have been pushed to machine this morning when I signed on) but no one else on my team is experiencing the same issues.

I'm not sure what to try next. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, is SSO still working for BizTalk? If so, this might just be a simple user level config issue for SSO.  based on the browser info, some user local settings may have been messed up. Try this:

1. CD to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Enterprise Single Sign-On" Use administrator privileges
2. Type: ssomanage -server [SSO Server Name Here]

This will reset the SSO Server name for your user account.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it.  And yes, SSO was still working for BizTalk while I was getting the error.

Comment: Fixed my problem - just note that the server name is not necessarily the same as where SSODB is located (in my case it was the local host)

Comment: Thanks for this.  NB: If you want to see what it's set to (or whether it's set) you can run `ssoclient -showserver`